# Error updating Percona Server

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, percona

I'm getting errors doing a regular aptitude safe-upgrade of percona-server-server-5.5, I'm already running a version of percona server 5.5

```
Setting up libmysqlclient18 (5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze) ...
Setting up percona-server-common-5.5 (5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze) ...
Setting up percona-server-client-5.5 (5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze) ...
Setting up percona-server-client (5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze) ...
Setting up percona-server-server-5.5 (5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze) ...
Stopping MySQL (Percona Server): mysqld.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/percona-server-server-5.5.postinst: line 63: 30956 Done                    echo "$replace_query"
     30957 Killed                  | $MYSQL_BOOTSTRAP 2>&1
     30958 Killed                  | $ERR_LOGGER
dpkg: error processing percona-server-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 137
configured to not write apport reports
                                      dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of percona-server-server:
 percona-server-server depends on percona-server-server-5.5; however:
  Package percona-server-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing percona-server-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up xtrabackup (1.6.5-328.squeeze) ...
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 percona-server-server-5.5
 percona-server-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up percona-server-server-5.5 (5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze) ...
Stopping MySQL (Percona Server): mysqld.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/percona-server-server-5.5.postinst: line 63: 31163 Done                    echo "$fix_privs"
     31164 Killed                  | $MYSQL_BOOTSTRAP 2>&1
     31165 Killed                  | $ERR_LOGGER
dpkg: error processing percona-server-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 137
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of percona-server-server:
 percona-server-server depends on percona-server-server-5.5; however:
  Package percona-server-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing percona-server-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 percona-server-server-5.5
 percona-server-server
```

Output from dkpg:

# dpkg --list | grep -E 'mysql|percona'

```
ii  libmysqlclient18                    5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze   Percona Server database client library
ii  percona-server-client               5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze   Percona Server database client
ii  percona-server-client-5.5           5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze   Percona Server database client binaries
ii  percona-server-common-5.5           5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze   Percona Server database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf)
iU  percona-server-server               5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze   Percona Server database server
iF  percona-server-server-5.5           5.5.20-rel24.1-217.squeeze   Percona Server database server binaries
ii  php5-mysql                          5.3.10-1~dotdeb.1            MySQL module for php5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a repository bug. Please file a bug on launchpad.net/percona-server/.